# Insert Icon inside Javascript - PHP dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu geneated by php and javascript. The code is the below one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    <?php $query = "sp_region_info 0";
    $select_region_query = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($select_region_query)) {
        $region_id = $row['region_id'];
        $region_name = $row['region_name'];
        $result_array[]= $region_name;
    }
    $json_array = json_encode($result_array);
    ?>
    var country = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;
    $("#region").select2({
        data: country
    });
});
</script>

<div class="input-group col-sm-3 search">
   <label class="bd-form-label">Destination</label>
   <select id="country"></select>
</div>
```

It is working properly I can search and use it as dropdown.

I was wonder whats the way to display next to results an icon?

e.g

That's my result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2FhA.png

And I need to display my Icon next to Destination title:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq0Z0.png

I tried by adding `<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>` inside my div but doesnt work..

Any thoughts ?

Comment: You should use `formatSelection` option of the plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `<i>` tag in `select option`, instead you can use **unicode**:

```
 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($select_region_query)) {
        $region_id = $row['region_id'];
        $region_name = $row['region_name'] . ' &#xf041;';
        $result_array[]= $region_name;
    }
```

and use this `css`:

```
.select2-results__option {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'Tahoma'
}
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rLmztr2d/157/)**

OR a simpler solution is using pseudo element:

```
.select2-results__option::after {
    content: "\f041";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rLmztr2d/158/)**

Answer (score 3):

Add the `<i>` within your while loop like this:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($select_region_query)) {
        $region_id = $row['region_id'];
        $region_name = $row['region_name'].'&#xf041;';
        $result_array[]= $region_name;
    }
```

Comment: That's not how the plugin works. Should be done in the formatting callback of the plugin

Comment: Dont work like that.. ... I get <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> as text on my dropdown

Comment: No @HimanshuUpadhyay.. Get that code as text.. But it worked with pseudo element.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it just using css, for example:

```
.select2-results__option:after {
    content: '\F041';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: pink;
}
```

Thats work for me)